# Does Quick Reconnoiter let me use Hear the Unseen as a free action?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

I have the *Complete Adventurer*, and I saw these two feats:

> **Hear the Unseen**
> **Benefit**: As a move action that does not provoke attacks of opportunity, you can attempt a DC 25 Listen check. If successful, you can pinpoint the location of all foes within 30 feet, as long as you have line of effect to them.
>
> **Quick Reconnoiter**
> **Benefit**: You can make one Spot check and one Listen check each round as a free action.
> **Normal**: Using Spot or Listen in a reactive fashion is a free action, but actively trying to make a Spot check or Listen check requires a move action.

If I have both, do they combine and let me use **Hear the Unseen** as a free action? I'm assuming they don't, but I wanted to be sure, because of what it says under what normally happens without the Quick Reconnoiter feat.

Comment: I just found in the Complete Scoundrel that I could pick up a skill trick that is better than "Hear the unseen" and is a free action. I'd still like an answer to my question though, if anyone knows.

Comment: Are you thinking of *Clarity of Vision?*  It is a swift action, not a free action, and usable only once per combat.  (That's true of all skill tricks.)  So the feat's ability is actually better if you can do it as a free action.

Comment: Interestingly, the [core rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#invisibility)  suggest that you only need a DC20 listen check to pinpoint an invisible creature engaged in combat.

Comment: It's DC 0 to get the hunch for a creature in combat or speaking, and "It’s practically impossible to pinpoint the location of an invisible creature. A Listen check that beats the DC by 20 pinpoints the invisible creature’s location. "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like yes.  Quick Reconnoiter doesn't specify the kind of Spot or Listen check you need to make for it to be a free action, so it looks like that combo lets you Hear the Unseen as a free action.  There may be errata making Quick Reconnoiter more specific, and I could definitely see many GMs not going along with it, but by RAW it checks out.

Comment: Worth pointing out that if you *pinpoint* an invsible enemy, you still have the 50% miss chance etc.  You just know which square they're in at the time you use the ability.

Comment: That's why I got a Seeking weapon. Mwahahaha.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that **no**, you cannot use Hear the Unseen as a free action. Simply put, Hear the Unseen specifies that the *to use the feat itself, you must take a move action*. The fact that you must then make a Listen check as **part** of that move action does not mean that the Listen check **is** the move action.

If the feat did not specify that you must take a move action, I would argue that the Listen check **is** the action, and agree with DuckTapeal.

Comment: But *Quick Reconnoiter* allows you to make *any* listen check as a free action; one feat is allowed to alter how you use another feat.  And *Hear the Unseen* makes it very clear that the move action is used for the listen check.  "*As* a move action... you can attempt a DC25 Listen check."  The benefits of the feat follow from the successful listen check.

Comment: @starwed you can now make listen checks as free actions, but to hear the unseen you need to use a move action nevertheless. The benefits of the feat follow from a successful listen check and spending a move action. Keep in mind that a listen check cuold have been a free action if it was a passive one (asked by the DM) even without the _quick reconnoiter_ feat.

Comment: @Zachiel This particular check could not have been free, because it is not reactive.